# How to get `placemark` property?

Tags: ios

I want to get `country` property of current locations.I have tested this code on simulator.And I have set the fake locations to `apple headquarter`.

**Code:**

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        geo=[[CLGeocoder alloc]init];
        pm=[[CLPlacemark alloc]init];
        lm=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
        lm.delegate=self;
        [lm startUpdatingLocation];

        }

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *loc=[[CLLocation alloc]init];
    loc=[locations lastObject];
    [geo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray *ARR,NSError *ERRO)

    {

    if(ERRO==nil&&[ARR count]>0)
    {
    pm=[ARR objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",pm.country);

    }
    else

    {
    NSLog(@"%@",ERRO.debugDescription);
    }



    }];

}
```

**Problem:It is showing exception on line `pm=[ARR objectAtIndex:0];` i.e  `exc_bad_access`**

Is something wrong with code or we can't test it on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the variable within the block:

```
[geo reverseGeocodeLocation:loc completionHandler:^(NSArray *ARR, NSError *ERRO)
{
    if(ERRO == nil && [ARR count] > 0)
    {
        CLPlacemark *pm = [ARR objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",pm.country);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",ERRO.debugDescription);
    }
}];
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you @unheilig . But it is creating `CLPlaceMark` instance no. of times.